# Force extent to ST_AsRaster() function in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql

I am trying to create a raster from a PostGIS `geometry`, the issue is that wherever features are missing PostGIS tries to reduce the extent of the raster. But I do not want this behaviour.

Can I force extent in PostGIS raster, i am using the following code.

```
WITH q AS (                        
WITH a AS (                
    SELECT 
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1840136.2116530193 4984382.618753927, 1840136.2116530193 4989382.618753927, 1845136.2116530193 4989382.618753927, 1845136.2116530193 4984382.618753927, 1840136.2116530193 4984382.618753927))', 3857) 
        AS geom            
)            
SELECT 
    ST_Transform(a.geom, 4326) 
    AS geom            
FROM a                
),                

features AS (            
    SELECT                 
    ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(t.wkb_geometry, q.geom), 3857) 
    AS geom            
    FROM                 
        public.gis_osm_roads_free_1 t,                
        q            
    WHERE                 
        ST_Intersects(t.wkb_geometry, q.geom)                
        AND                
        1=1        
),

q1 AS (
    SELECT ST_AsRaster(
        ST_Collect(features.geom),                         
        100,                         
        100,                         
        '8BUI'::text,                         
        1,                         
        254,                         
        1840136.2116530193,                         
        4989382.618753927,                         
        0,                        
        0,                        
        false                 
    ) as ras
    FROM features
)

SELECT 
ST_AsTIFF(
               q1.ras,
                'LZW'
            )
FROM q1
```

Comment: The function ST_AsRaster() converts a vector geometry to raster.